# How to add an item to the top of the array and delete in Java?

Tags: java

I have:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000]
```

I need:

```
[-100,10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0]
```

How to add items to the top and delete items of the array in Java ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, show us what you have tried and attempted in in your code and we'll be more than happy to point you in the right direction. You just need to show effort first!

Comment: You know that you can reference an array's elements by index, right? So you want to change myArray[0] and myArray[7]. All you have to do is figure out how to do in in a loop which copies the contents of myArray[x] and moves it to myArray[x + 1], ensuring that x + 1 is never greater than myArray.size() - 1.

Comment: Thank you for all! I am using LinkedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an removing an item from an array is expensive. You may find a lot of example by googling. But I would like to use a different data structure here. Map could be a good solution in this case.  You may use `Map` like this -

```
Map<Integer, Integer> dummyArrayByMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

After that you can user `dummyArrayByMap` to put any element at any index like this -

```
dummyArrayByMap.put(3, 234) //put 234 at index 3
dummyArrayByMap.put(9, 234) //put 235 at index 9 
dummyArrayByMap.put(1, 234) //put 24 at index 1
```

And when you try  to remove something from first index then you may use the following code sniippet -

```
if(dummyArrayByMap.get(1)!=null){
   dummyArrayByMap.remove(1);
}
```

After removing an element from the first index you can easily add a new value again at the first index -

```
dummyArrayByMap.put(1, 387) // now new value is put at index 1 that means at first.
```

Comment: What is a cheap method without shifting elements? I want 'move' head and delete tail, like [2,3,4,5,6] => [1,2,3,4,5] –  int13h

Comment: @int13, May be I am wrong. But I think - since array is fixed by size so for shifting we have to create an new array which size would be `theOldArraySize+1`. After that we have to add an item as first item at index 0. Then copy all of the item to the old array to the newly created array.

Comment: Size is const. I want to find a cheap method to moving: [ 2,3............1000]  => [1,2.........999]  - adding element to head and remove tail

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
int[] array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000];
int[] temp = array;

for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = array[i - 1];
}

array = temp;
array[0] = -100; // the new input
```